# Copy selected records from interactive grid to another one Oracle apex5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i am new to oracle apex and i am using oracle apex 5.1

i am trying the copy the selected records from an interactive grid in a modal page to another interactive grid in the main page (page calling the modal page).

i have tried many method like getSelectedRecords and setSelectedRecords, model.fetchRecords and many more but with no luck. The below method was the closest one to what i wanted to achive:

```
var labTemplateData = apex.region("modalInteractiveGrid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model._data;  
parent.apex.region("parentInteractiveGrid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model._data = labTemplateData;
```

the data in parentInteractiveGrid was update (i checked it in chrome developer tools) but it was not shown in the grid. am i missing a refresh or update? Or is there a better way to do it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google showed a good explanation of how to get the results of an Interactive Grid into a Collection. From there, you could save the collection to your table, then refresh your main page once you've closed the modal page.

Comment: The problem is that I need to update the Grid without reloading the page. Because reloading the main page will reload the data from the database into the grid (because it's based on a query). so i need to get the data from the modal page Grid and replace the Grid (in the parent page) with this data without reloading the whole page.

Comment: That's a pretty unique requirement. 

What if your Grid was based on a collection? You initially load the collection from the database and display it in the grid. Then when the modal is closed, you save to the collection, then refresh the grid from the collection.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i will try it. Thank you